# Adding New Relationships in Neo4j Database using apoc.periodic.iterate

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I have a Neo4j database with two kinds of nodes - Authors and Articles. Some of the articles have more than one author. I am trying to create an undirected relationship between the authors who worked together on an article. My current non-functional query is this:

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
    "MATCH (a:Author) WHERE (a)-[:WROTE]->()<-[:WROTE]-(b:Author) RETURN a,b",
    "WITH {a} AS a, {b} as b CREATE (a)-[r:COAUTHOR]-(b)", {batchSize:10000, parallel:true})
```

I get the following error:

> Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.periodic.iterate`: Caused by: org.neo4j.exceptions.SyntaxException: PatternExpressions are not allowed to introduce new variables: 'b'. (line 1, column 60 (offset: 59))
> "EXPLAIN MATCH (a:Author) WHERE (a)-[:WROTE]->()<-[:WROTE]-(b:Author) RETURN a,b"

I can see that the issue is that I am trying to do too much in the first MATCH statemetn, but I'm new to Cypher and am having trouble breaking it up.

Thanks very much,
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem stems from your first statement:

```
MATCH (a:Author)
WHERE (a)-[:WROTE]->()<-[:WROTE]-(b:Author)
RETURN a,b
```

Cypher does not allow introducing new variables on the `WHERE` part of the query, so your `(b:Author)` will not be allowed since it's located on the `WHERE` clause.

To fix, move `(b:Author)` to the `MATCH` statement. Also, if you are finding a pattern on the `WHERE` clause, you should use the `exists()` function in order to return a boolean.

```
MATCH (a:Author), (b:Author)
WHERE exists((a)-[:WROTE]->()<-[:WROTE]-(b))
RETURN a, b
```